# Nested For Loops in Python (calculating the perimeters of triangles)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to calculate perimeters of triangles. I want to access concrete elements of the list, so I am using a nested for loop. 1)
I would like to know why the position of `perimeter` makes my code different in both variants. (in the second one I don't understand why the output is 240)
2) I would like to know how to concatenate all items in the nested lists, so the output should be like that: (I tried using indexing, but it didn't work)

```
60
150
240
```

The First:

```
def function(triangle):
    perimeter = 0
    for i in triangle:
        for j in i:
            perimeter = perimeter + j
    return perimeter

function([[10,20,30], [40,50,60], [70,80,90]])
450
```

The Second:

```
def function(triangle):
    for i in triangle:
        perimeter = 0
        for j in i:
            perimeter = perimeter + j
    return perimeter

function([[10,20,30], [40,50,60], [70,80,90]])
240
```

Comment: I've edited your examples to correct apparent indentation errors - if the revision is not correct you should fix it.  [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Your first example produces an Exception: `NameError: name 'geom' is not defined`

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  Are you using an IDE with debugging features? If so now is an excellent time to get familiar with them. Or spend some time learning the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#module-pdb). Printing *stuff* at strategic points is often useful for tracing execution. There are also online visualizers like [pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

Comment: So sorry for inattention! My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - The difference between two codes is that, in the first one `perimeter` is set to 0 before the loop starts, and than updated throughout the loop. In the second one, you set the `perimeter` value to 0 every time the outer loop is executed, so the value from previous loop is not accumulated in it.

2- For loop you can use the following method:

```
triangles = [[10,20,30], [40,50,60], [70,80,90]]
perimeters = list(map(sum,triangles))
print(perimeters)
[60, 150, 240]
```

Here, `map` iterates over the elements of `triangles` and calls the `sum` function for each element. Then, using `list` you can convert it to a list of perimeter values.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to return the perimeters of each triangle supplied to your function.

This can be expressed almost directly in python:

```
def get_perimeters(triangles):
    return [sum(perimeters) for perimeters in triangles]

print(get_perimeters([[10,20,30], [40,50,60], [70,80,90]]))
```

Output:

```
[60, 150, 240]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example - since you set perimeter to be zero before you start looping through any of the triangles, you calculate the total perimieter of all of the listed triangles.

By moving the `perimeter = 0` inside the outer loop (in your 2nd example), you are discarding the total for the first triangle after you calculate it, and then you are discarding the total for the 2nd triangle before you calculate it again for the third.

I would re-write your code like this :

```
def perimeters(geom):
    for triangle in geom:
         yield sum(triangle)
```

you now have a generator which you can loop around - or convert to a list, or pass to a function such as map, filter etc.

```
for perimeter in perimeters([[10,20,30], [40,50,60], [70,80,90]])
    print(perimeter)
```

The Benefit of using generators is that it calculates the data when you need it, rather than doing all the caulculations up front.

Answer (score 0):

Minor fix for return all perimeter as list

```
def function(triangle):
    perimeter_list = []
    for i in triangle:
        perimeter = 0
        for j in i:
            perimeter = perimeter + j
        perimeter_list.append(perimeter)
    return perimeter_list

function([[10,20,30], [40,50,60], [70,80,90]])
```

Output

```
[60, 150, 240]
```